# Elaborar tabela do banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela em CSS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar as tabelas do banco de dados MySQL, porém, não sei bem como trabalhar isto... Irá ser apenas "Atualizado" todas as informações na tabela...
O que me preocupa é as faixas de porcentagens... Como eu poderia desenvolver isto? Faço uma tabela para cada? Ex: parametros_inss (idParametroInss, faixa, valorInicial, valorFinal, porcentagem) sendo inserido: (1, 1, 0,00, 1.000,00, 8%)...

Alguém aqui tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Boa tarde André, recomendo que faça títulos mais intuitivos. Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: Ok! Valeu Guilherme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, se até onde eu entendi você esta com problemas perante a modelagem.

Até onde identifiquei você irá trabalhar com muitos registros, com muitos pais e muitos filhos, tirando a possibilidade de se fazer um relacionamento 1:n.

Eu não sei se muitos vão concordar, mas eu a principio faria uma tabela de storages de valores, onde a cada valor eu definiria uma chave e uma categoria para ela, no valor eu jogaria os valores desta categoria e faixa como `json_encode`

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu faria uma query:

```
SELECT * FROM storages where `category` = 'faixa_inss' and `key` = '1_faixa'
```

Esta query iria me retornar todos os valores da categoria `faixa_inss` e que sejam `1_faixa`.

No `JSON`eu tenho um array com os valores, qual você poderá trabalhar com eles.

Assim você poderia fazer vários registros de storages. Quando quiser mudar é só recuperar o array pelo json, manipular e salvar novamente como json.

Assim, na minha opinião, seu banco ficará mais legível e performático.

Veja [estrutura do banco](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86417/2) no SQLFIDDLE

Comment: É uma opção interessante, vale ressaltar que vou ter que adicionar idEmpresa, e idProfissao, cada empresa, poderá ter seu rol de profissões, que por sua vez, poderá ter estes parâmetros mencionados... Acredito que só alterando sua estrutura, seria válido, o que me diz? Grato pela idéia.

Comment: É só colocar na tabela storages respectivos campos, pois cada empresa e profissão terão sua storage. Ficará `id | idEmpresa | idProfissao | category | key | value`

Comment: Exato, e para adicionar da forma que você criou, storage: usaria então o serialize()?

Comment: serialize($this['data']);

Comment: @AndréBaill sim. Para decidir usar serialize ou json_encode recomendo dar uma lida: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta, @AndréBaill

Comment: Na verdade, já uso o serialize para permissoes do sistema, com isso, conseguiria trabalhar mais facilmente...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29644/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-juniorb2ss).

Comment: .Não consigo te responder no chat, diz que não estou logado

Comment: Só uma dúvida: Os que são 3 ou 4 faixas... eu usaria como? o nome dos campos? estou meio perdido ainda.

Comment: Andre, é uma tabela de storage. Você vai inserir na tabela a storage referente a esta faixa `category = faixa_inss and key = 2_faixa` e etc... Cada storage um novo registro.

Comment: @AndréBaill veja exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf22/1

Comment: Então, neste caso, era bem isso mesmo... porém, eu vou precisar destes parametros em outra hora, como farei a pesquisa se tal parametro existe... acho que complicaria mais, o que acha?